# Get Facebook post URL only in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, facebook

I want to get facebook recent post URL on my wall using pure javascript (with no use of the API).
regularly I would do that by clicking on the time/date the post was posted on and it will get load a new page including only that post.
In `Javascript`, the `a` element that will hold the last post URL would be:

```
let a = document.getElementsByClassName("oajrlxb2 g5ia77u1 qu0x051f esr5mh6w e9989ue4 r7d6kgcz rq0escxv nhd2j8a9 nc684nl6 p7hjln8o kvgmc6g5 cxmmr5t8 oygrvhab hcukyx3x jb3vyjys rz4wbd8a qt6c0cv9 a8nywdso i1ao9s8h esuyzwwr f1sip0of lzcic4wl gmql0nx0 gpro0wi8 b1v8xokw")[0];
```

The problem is that `a.href`'s value (at default) will be `https://www.facebook.com/#`, and only when I hover over the time/date then the `a.href`'s value will be changed to the actual recent post URL.
I tried to simulate that mouse hover by `a.dispatchEvent(new Event('mouseover'))` with no success.
I also collected all the eventListeners of all relevant elements of the last post by running over all the `a`'s parents/children and `getEventListeners()` function, fired 'em all up with no success also.

Comment: _"In Javascript, the a element that will hold the last post URL would be:"_ - for right now, perhaps. But these class names will not stay fix like that, you can expect to see different ones at any point in the future.

Comment: You can freeze the page by going to the Sources page in the Dev Tools and then pressing F8. Using that technique you can hover over the href, then freeze the page, and then inspect the frozen element.

Comment: @EldarB. Actually I don't need to do that, because whenever I hover over the `a` element, its `href` value's changes to the actual URL that I need forever, which means that the `href` value's doesn't change anymore, regardless where hover my mouse.
What I needed is pure Javascript solution, without the need of physically moving my mouse/ physically interacting with the page

Comment: Why not just use the API, like intended?

Comment: @EldarB. my task is very simple and its just getting posts once in a while, so I thought that its too simple task for using (and learning) API